# How to hide website directory from search engines without Robots.txt?

Tags: security, search-engine, robots.txt

We know we can stop search engines  from indexing directories on our site using robots.txt.

But this of course has the disadvantage of actually publicising directories we don't want found to possible attackers.

Password protecting the directory using .htaccess or other means is obviously the best way to keep the directory private.

But what if, for reasons of convenience, we didn't want to add another layer of security to the directory and just wanted to add another level of obfuscation? To hide, for example, an admin login page.

Is there another way to "hide" the directory without broadcasting its location in a robots.txt file?

Comment: Isn't an `.htaccess` more convenient?

Comment: No because then user would need to login to see the login page

Comment: Do you have any links to your admin login page (or the other pages you wish to hide) which are accessible from the public portion of your site?  If not, you don't need to tell search engines not to index those pages as they will never find out about them anyway.

Comment: no, but it's just the admin login page that needs to be hidden

Answer (score 1):

Here is *what* to do, please note as you haven't mentioned any particular technology I haven't included *how* to do it.

If you configure your web server to output the following `meta` tag in the directory listing HTML page, it will [prevent your page from being indexed by compliant search engines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en).

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Adding this would probably require implementing a custom module within your web server that will override the default directory listing output page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a random string. Something like http://website.com/some-random-string-here/file.html

The remember not use some-random-string-here in your robots.txt file or on any links.

Comment: Search engines will still pick this up unless you explicitly put it in the robots file

Comment: I tried this and as long as I put a blank index.html in there along with file.html, I have yet to see them appear online. Granted, this is might be more luck than design.