# How to solve robots.txt vlunerability to tell important and secret paths to hackers?

Tags: security, path, robots.txt

These days **robots.txt** became an important tool for SEO in websites. Through this file, web developers says crawler robots to check and not to check specific paths. But on the other hand, there are many secret and important directories and files inside websites that their paths must not mention anywhere to anyone to decrease security risks. Speaking about them is like giving a map to a thief to find all doors.
The problem is that robots.txt is in plain format and easy to read by every body because it almost stores in root directory with full read permission. So if I have a file like this

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /admin/
```

I am saying to everybody (specially hackers): "I have a directory named **admin** and it must not be crawled". Whereas I did not like others know there is such directory in my website.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should ask yourself why would the knowledge of the *existence* of such a directory be a security risk. Is it the knowledge of that directory, or is it the fact that knowing that the directory exists would allow someone to get into that directory? Why aren't you using HTTP authorization features to limit the users that can get in there? Then a crawler or other nefarious user wouldn't be able to get in there, and it wouldn't matter if they knew about it or not.

Comment: You could do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25011819/413180), although this is only possible on HTML content. unor's solution is better, although it should be thoroughly tested to make sure common search engines obey a partial match as intended. Make sure you sufficiently secure your admin pages with strong passwords, password lockout and ideally 2FA. Also see OWASP Top 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the beginning of the URL path only.

In case of `/admin/`, you could for example specify:

```
Disallow: /adm
```

You just have to find the string that only blocks the URLs you want to block, and not others (like `/administer-better`).

Depending on your URL structure, it might make sense to add a path segment to all "secret" URLs, and only refer to this segment in your robots.txt, and not the following segments:

```
Disallow: /private/
# nothing to see when visiting /private/ 
# the secret URLs are:
#   /private/admin/
#   /private/login/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the X-Robots-Tag in the page you don't want to be crawled .

But I really prefer a IP whitelist when is available .